# Json datasource binding

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, kendo-mobile

I'm trying to bind a json object to kendo mobile listview, but the listview binds all characters in json array including brackets and quotes.

```
function loadtypes() {

                $("#pull-to-refresh-listview").empty();
                var murl = "/Home/getTypes/";
                $.ajax({
                    url: murl,
                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {

                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data.TypesViewModel));

                        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: JSON.stringify(data.TypesViewModel) });



                        $("#pull-to-refresh-listview").kendoMobileListView({
                            dataSource: dataSource,
                            //template: "#: type_name #",
                            filterable: true,

                            virtualViewSize: 50 // needed setting, since local data virtualization does not use paging
                        });

                        return dataSource;

                    },
                    error: function (reponse) {
                        return '{"error":"Error"}';
                    }
                });
            }

Controller:

public ActionResult AddTypes(TypeModel model)
        {
            rep = new GroceryRepository();

            rep.AddType(model);

            return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**JSON:**

> [{"id":0,"type_name":"Beverages"},{"id":0,"type_name":"Meat"},{"id":0,"type_name":"test"},{"id":0,"type_name":"test2"},{"id":0,"type_name":"test3"},{"id":0,"type_name":"test4"},{"id":0,"type_name":"test5"},{"id":0,"type_name":"test7"},{"id":0,"type_name":"test8"},{"id":0,"type_name":"type6"}]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are turning your JSON into a string with `JSON.stringify`.